# | Not Working In Subprocess.call

Tags: python, command, subprocess, shlex

Whenever I use a command in a subprocess with "|" in it doesn't work it has an output of 
    Command "|" is unknown, try "in link help". 
Or when I put this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import call
from shlex import split

interface = call(split("ip -o link show | awk '{print $2}' | grep wl"))
```

It is giving the output of:

```
Error: either "dev" is duplicate, or "awk" is a garbage.
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.check_output` method and `Popen` class though I wasn't able to chain both pipe operations. Partial solution:

```
from subprocess import check_output, Popen, PIPE
from shlex import split

process = Popen(split('ip -o link show'), stdout=PIPE)
output = check_output(('awk', '{print $2}'), stdin=process.stdout)
return_code = process.wait()
print(output, return_code)
```

So basically, awk is taking the `process` standard output, and result is saved in the `output` variable.